# Code cutting off string after runs many times

Tags: c#, string, text-files, streamwriter

This code runs in a loop. After the 38th time it runs, the string that gets printed to the text file cuts off immediately after the second "M", doesn't even print the comma, and then stops printing everything and ends.

What could be the cause of this?

```
private static void LogPayment(CDefeasancePayment paymentToLog, System.IO.StreamWriter outfile)
{
    string line = "AddDefeasancePayment(DateTime.Parse(\"" + paymentToLog.PaymentDate.ToShortDateString() +
                  "\"), " + paymentToLog.Interest +
                  "M, " + paymentToLog.Principal + "M, DateTime.Parse(\"" +
                  paymentToLog.StripDate.ToShortDateString() + "\"), " + paymentToLog.StripPrice +
                  "M);\n";
    outfile.Write(line);
}
```

Comment: have you set AutoFlush property of outfile to true ?

Comment: 38th is not the last. @PierrOz - how do I set autoflush?

Comment: Yup it was AutoFlush. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you have flushed your `outfile` buffer.

Comment: @slandau: When you `Dispose` the `StreamWriter`, `Flush` will be called.

Comment: @slandau: and you can call `outfile.Flush()` whenever you deem it necessary. However, given that this is a logfile (and you want to see the output immediately), autoflush should serve you fine.